# How should I approach dynamic layout in my app based on the information from my backend?

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am building an app which will receive data from my backend and provide dynamic layout in the app. Let me explain. Let's say I am building an image editing app which let's you place text, png stickers etc on the image. The app needs to have templates which can place the text, stickers etc on the image.

Let's say, the user selects an image and text "Happy new year". I want to show the user a bunch of different ways the "Happy new year" text can be placed on top of the image to look nice. So things like font, text color, alignment, text placement on the image, masking the text from a circle for some cool billboard looking effects , placing png of star and other design around the text etc.

Ideally I don't want to have to update my app every time I want to add a new template. I want the app to get new template information from my server and add it in. I am just not sure how should go about building my own dynamic layout system. Things like textColor, font is easy. However text placement on the image (center, top left, top right, bottom etc), the size of the text, alignment etc information is hard for me to define.

Should I even use autolayout for this? How should I define things like "pin the text center to image center", place a "star" png on top of the text centered etc. And how should I represent this information in JSON?

NOTE: Please do not suggest HTML and CSS, I need it to be full native iOS code.

Comment: You have to send point by point information of lay out  for example you want to show a stick on image 
you will be in need  to tell device  on what x and what y which hieght and what width should this item show, 
you will also have to send type of element you want to user for that sticker which mean you will be in need to add a viewType it may be textField UIImage , UITextView, UILabel , and on  device end you have to create a method that will pick the  element of type. 
so some like this